# response data returning null when url works

Tags: ios, xcode4.3

I'm trying to get some data sent from my app to a web server.

What the app is supposed to do is display a list of members, show their details when selected and give the ability to edit their details. so far everything except for editing is working.

The error message i'm getting is

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'

The app works fine up until

```
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

It appears that responseData is null. I can't understand it since the url that is generated works fine when entered into the browser.

This is the whole code for the updating details

```
- (IBAction)submitEdits:(id)sender {
    smdbs_AppData *appData = [smdbs_AppData sharedInstance];
    NSString *loggedInID=appData.loggedInID;

    NSString *member = [self.memberDetailModel objectAtIndex:3];

    NSURL *urlLogin = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xxx/API.php?task=setMemberDetails&id=%@&mem_id=%@&section=%@&firstName=%@&lastName=%@&membershipNo=%@&DOB=%@&gender=%@&school=%@&religion=%@&ethnicity=%@&photoPerm=%@&swimPerm=%@&giftaid=%@&giftaidperson=%@&address1=%@&address2=%@&town=%@&county=%@&postCode=%@&homeTelNo=%@&mother=%@&motherMobile=%@&father=%@&fatherMobile=%@&other=%@&relationship=%@&otherTelNo=%@&email1=%@&email2=%@&doctor=%@&surgery=%@&docTelNo=%@&allergiesMed=%@&specialNeeds=%@&pack=%@&six=%@&joinedScouting=%@&joinedBeavers=%@&joinedCubs=%@&joinedScouts=%@&joinedYLs=%@&joinedHelpers=%@&joinedLeaders=%@&crbDate=%@&crbNo=%@", loggedInID, member, self.section.text, self.firstName.text, self.lastName.text, self.membershipNo.text, self.DOB.text, self.gender.text, self.school.text, self.religion.text, self.ethnicity.text, self.photoPerm.text, self.swimPerm.text, self.giftaid.text, self.giftaidperson.text, self.address1.text, self.address2.text, self.town.text, self.county.text, self.postCode.text, self.homeTelNo.text, self.mother.text, self.motherMobile.text, self.father.text, self.fatherMobile.text, self.other.text, self.relationship.text, self.otherTelNo.text, self.email1.text, self.email2.text, self.doctor.text, self.surgery.text, self.docTelNo.text, self.allergiesMed.text, self.specialNeeds.text, self.pack.text, self.six.text, self.joinedScouting.text, self.joinedBeavers.text, self.joinedCubs.text, self.joinedScouts.text, self.joinedYLs.text, self.joinedHelpers.text, self.joinedLeaders.text, self.crbDate.text, self.crbNo.text]];

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* editData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlLogin];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(EditData:)
                               withObject:editData waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

- (void)EditData:(NSData *)responseData
{
    NSError* error;
    NSLog(@"%@",responseData);
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSString* success =  [json objectForKey:@"success"];

    if ([success isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showMemberDetails" sender:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not catching any errors while downloading data. Use sendSynchronousRequest class method of NSURLConnection instead `+ (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error` and log the error to see why is it failing.

Comment: I'm getting the message

"Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x6866740 {NSUnderlyingError=0x68694c0 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}"

Comment: You need to encode the URL. That might be the problem.

Comment: How would i go about doing that? I'm relatively new to iOS development

Comment: Take out the URL string from NSURL and then use NSString method stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: to encode that URL string then pass it to NSURL.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have solved it